# Question about installing a compiler/interpreter for a programming language - off topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, off-topic

I noticed that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720031/the-title-is-irrelevant-at-this-point-no) was closed as off topic because it is about installing libraries for a compiler/interpreter for a programming language. Unfortunately you have to look at the question's edit history to get the gist of the original question since it has been edited.

But anyway, according to the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), a question is on topic if it covers:

> software tools commonly used by programmers

So was the original question really off topic?

Comment: "commonly" strikes again. Plus, we have to visit some link to see what the error log was?

Comment: @random I rolled the destructive edit back and edited in the error log. Still not a great question, but at least it's self-contained now.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Softpedia's article on Chicken](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Compilers/Chicken-1741.shtml):

> Chicken is a compiler app for the Scheme programming language.
>
> Chicken produces efficient and portable C, and it supports many of the current Scheme language standard (see the list below for details).

Compiling Scheme, a functional programming language often used in computer science academic departments, into C code sounds deceptively like something a programmer might be more interested in than a power user.  Even most programmers may not regularly interact with Scheme. For instance, I haven't touched it since my functional programming course at the university.

While installing software, on the surface, is something that does fit Super User, in general, people asking questions about software on Super User are mostly looking at solving basic, everyday computer problems or even problems faced by power users, not professional programmers.

This question, while on-topic on Super User, is more likely to receive an answer on Stack Overflow since there are more Scheme experts on Stack Overflow than there are in a site for computer enthusiasts and power users.  If the question is about installing Microsoft Word, then sure, vote to close and refer the user to Super User. But when the software is something so specific that only advanced software developers will understand it, then Stack Overflow is the correct place for the question.

I've voted to reopen this question, and I encourage others to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The question probably would have been completely accepted at the [Askubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com) site. I think that you might have better luck if you try on one of the specialized sites instead of the main SO site. The question might even be eligible for [superuser](http://www.superuser.com) since it's configuration and how you set up your environment rather than programming and actual program writing.

> > What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> computer hardware, computer software, or personal and home computer
>   networking and **it is not about …
>
> programming** and software development, video games or consoles,
>   websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
>   electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except
>   insofar as they interface with your computer, issues specific to
>   corporate IT support and networks, asking for a shopping or product
>   recommendation,

Comment: Power users and computer enthusiasts aren't the same as advanced professional programmers who have knowledge of obscure, functional programming languages like Scheme. Your suggestion isn't terrible though, as the question would certainly be on topic on Ask Ubuntu or Super User, but it shouldn't be off-topic on the site which contains a higher percentage of experts in that topic, the elusive Scheme programming language.